# django model foreignkeys question

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am very new to programming and databases and I have a question about foreignkeys in django.

Say I have a model called `Expenses` that has a foreignkey pointed to `Employees` model.

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    ...

class Expenses(models.Model):
    ...
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employees)
```

I see that foreignkey field is an employee ID.

So my question is, if in practice I have an `employee's name` accessible to me on a form, I would have to:

1. get the `employee id` from the `Employees` table with the name
2. Insert the `employee id` as the foreign key into the Expenses table like this:

   emp_id = Employees.object.get(name = 'John Doe')

   new_expense = Expenses(foo = 'bar', ..., employee_id = emp_id.employee_id,)
   new_expenses.save()

Am I doing this right? If so is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model class names should be singular. This will read much better in Python. You can have the associated database table have a different name by using `class Meta:` inside the model class. Also, the default Manager is `objects`, not `object`.

You don't need to go through all that trouble. Django will take care of mapping IDs. It creates a "reverse" field in the destination model of the `ForeignKey`. The name of this reverse connection is the name of the model with the ForeignKey plus `_set`. So, in your case, `Employees` will have an auto-generated field named `expenses_set` which acts as a manager containing all that employee's expenses. The manager has methods such as `create` and `delete` as well. So your example is just:

```
new_expense = (Employee.objects.get(name='John Doe')
    .expense_set.create(foo='bar', ...))
```

Though it's better to keep tabs on the `Employee` object:

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(name='John Doe')
new_expense = employee.expense_set.create(foo='bar', ...)
```

(No spaces around `=` when used in parameter lists.) Note that you don't need to set the employee ID this way.

That said, most of us provide `ForeignKey` with a better name for that reverse link by using the `related_name` parameter:

```
class Expenses(models.Model):
    ...
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employees, related_name='expenses')

...
employee = Employee.objects.get(name='John Doe')
new_expense = employee.expenses.create(foo='bar', ...)
```

BTW, if you want to get the expenses for an employee, there are three ways. One is like above:

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(name='John Doe')
employee_expenses = employee.expenses.all()
```

Or the one-liner:

```
employee_expenses = Employee.objects.get(name='John Doe').expenses.all()
```

There's also:

```
employee_expenses = Expense.objects.filter(employee__name="John Doe")
```

The `__` says to dereference the ForeignKey to get to its fields. The first way does two queries, the others do one, but you don't get the intermediate `Employee` object for use later.